# Copy slides from multiple ppt files to a single ppt file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub Combine_ppt()

Dim parent As PowerPoint.Application
Dim child As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pname, cname As String

pname = "C:\PPT\ParentFile.ppt"
On Error Resume Next
Set parent = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
parent.Presentations.Open pname
On Error GoTo 0
If parent Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Parent File not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
parent.Visible = True
fld = "C:\PPT\"
cname = Dir(fld & "*Child*.ppt")
Do While cname <> ""
    Set child = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    child.Presentations.Open "C:\PPT\" & cname
    ccount = child.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    For i = 1 To ccount
        child.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).copy
        parent.ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i
    child.Quit
    Set child = Nothing
Loop
End Sub
```

I am trying to copy slides from all the ppt's having the word 'child' in their file name to a parent ppt. When I run the code , I see that the copied slide is pasted in to the same presentation instead of the parent and also the code goes in to an infinite loop opening the same child file again and again and not moving on the another child file in the folder. please advice.

Answer (score 0):

you are not looping over all the files in Dir because you missed to call Dir for every file

you just need to add a single sentence at the end of the loop

```
cname = Dir(fld & "*Child*.ppt")
Do While cname <> ""
   ...
   cname=Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how about the slide getting copy pasted in the same file when I have mentioned Child.copy and Parent .paste but it pastes in the Child only.

Comment: your code looks right to me, are you sure you posted your running code?

Comment: I missed adding the 'ActivePresentation' in parent.ActivePresentation.slides.paste and it is running but somehow still pasting in the same file. Also .Close does not work so I am using .Quit.

Comment: Your Child and Parent are the same application instances; PPT won't allow two instances of itself.  Instead, start one instance of PowerPoint.  Your Parent object should be a reference to the presentation you want to insert slides into, your child object(s) should be references to the presentation's you're inserting slides from.

Answer (score 0):

I modify it as shown below

```
Sub Combine_ppt()

    Dim parent As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim child As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pname, cname As String

    pfname = "123.pptx"
    pname = "D:\temp\PPT\" & pfname
    On Error Resume Next
    Set parent = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    parent.Presentations.Open pname
    On Error GoTo 0
    If parent Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Parent File not Found"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    parent.Visible = True
    fld = "D:\temp\PPT\"
    cname = Dir(fld & "*child*.pptx")
    Do While cname <> ""
        Set child = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        child.Presentations.Open "D:\temp\PPT\" & cname
        ccount = child.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

        For i = 1 To ccount
            'child.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Copy
            Presentations(child.ActivePresentation.Name).Slides(i).Copy
            'Presentations("ParentFile.pptx").Slides.Paste
            Presentations(pfname).Slides.Paste

        Next i

        'child.Quit
        Presentations(child.ActivePresentation.Name).Close
        Set child = Nothing
        cname = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```